# Could I replace RabbitMQ with native kubernetes messaging queue

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I didn't find could we replace rabbitMQ/activeMQ/SQS with native kubernetes messaging queue?
or they are totally different in terms of features?

Comment: What is native kubernetes messageing queue ?

Answer (score 4):

It is a totally different mechanism.

Kubernetes internal queues is not a real "queues" you can use in external applications, they are a part of internal messaging system and manage only objects which are parts of Kubernetes.

Moreover, Kubernetes doesn't provide any message queue as a service for external apps (except a situation when your app actually service one of K8s objects).

If you are not sure which service is better for your app - try to check [queues.io](https://github.com/lukaszx0/queues.io). 
That is a list of almost all available MQ engines with some highlights.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the [Parallel Processing Using a Work Queue](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/) approach, you can technically use any queuing system, because the main logic is in the code used to get the items from the queue, Kubernetes is used only to control the parallelism.

If the idea is to use the queue algorithm used internally by kubernetes. it is not exposed as a a service for external applications, you would have to copy the code and implement in you application.